# Install several parallel software files from the same msi/download url

Tags: cmd.exe, windows-installer

I have downloaded a free version of an email extractor which installs a exe and a msi file.  It consumes only 60 MB RAM.  I want to make 25-30 copies of it to run parallely.  Have Orca for msi and tried by changing guid but it does not install a new copy but gives repair/remove options when exe file is clicked. Have also installed resource tuner to alter exe version code but still same error.

What to do for making clones?

Comment: Product code, upgrade code, version number altered in orca.

Comment: Why would you not just run the application multiple times?

Comment: The email extractor is left 24 hrs running...

Comment: Yes, so what? Why would you need to change the INSTALLER for it to run multiple copies of it?

Comment: because the exe/msi files are not installing 'new' parallel program. exe shows repair/remove program even when fresh downloaded from the url.

Comment: in orca - transforms - add table - options are msiPatch metadata, msipatchsequence, msipatch assembly...what to add/alter

Comment: @Seth. Yes that works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simply running the application multiple times was the solution.

Credit to Seth in the comments.